# How to get variable from text file using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

So I made up this code:

```
sed -n -e '0,/version/{s/.*: *//p}' "$path"
```

$path is actual path to this file:

```
name: CSaveBackupWorld
main: ru.centurion.savebackupworld.SBW
version: 3.6
author: ASTRO
load: STARTUP
```

I just wanna get version value, I mean that 3.6, but instead of that I am getting this output:

```
CSaveBackupWorld
ru.centurion.savebackupworld.SBW
3.6
```

That is really strange, course I made a filter only for version, but it shows name and main too. What am I doing wrong?

First problem solved completely! Here is the last one:
I have one more file:

```
apply plugin: 'jee'

version = "1.3"
group= "com.centurion.eye" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "eye"
```

How can I get THAT version? Only 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needlessly added `0,` to your command:

```
sed -n -e '/version/{s/.*: *//p}' "$path"
```

should work just fine. `0,` makes `sed` print everything from the start of the file up to the matched line.

Alternatively, `awk` might be more readable:

```
awk '/version/{print $2}' "$path"
```

Comment: Thats solves problem. Cant you look again at my post? I`ve added some more code (another type of file). Thanks!

Comment: How about `awk '/version/{print $3}' "$path" | tr -d '"'`? @AndrewGG

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
 sed -n -e '/version/ s/.*: *//p' "$path"
```

will do it

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your problem in one shot.

```
sed -n 's/^version.*\([0-9]\.[0-9]\).*/\1/p' "$path"
```